# Android gradle plugin compatibility with latest Gradle versions

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Gradle build scan is always advising Android projects to use latest version of Gradle (now 4.0.2).

But is it really safe considering I'm not using the corresponding Android gradle plugin version.
Specifically, I'm using Android plugin 2.3.3 which was developed [with 3.x Gradle version in mind](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-gradle)) and not ready to upgrade to the newest 3.0.0-alpha* release branch.

Did you notice any build speed improvements or at contrary any regressions while **always** using the latest version of Gradle?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the canary build for Android Studio? If you have the stable version, it shouldn't be asking you to update. Based on the `implementation` option for dependencies (see [migration](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html)), and from my testing, there does seem to be notable speed increases with gradle. And gradle won't force you to sync when you edit a gradle file and undo it.

However, there are some issues with updating libraries to gradle 3.0.0, so if 2.3.3 works for you you my as well keep that for now.

Also keep in mind that you can install the canary AS alongside the stable version, so you can always create a branch and test out both to see which one you like more.